# 301 redirect conflicts with other 301 redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I ran into a redirect conflict and don't get it solved.
For example, I have following redirects:

```
redirect 301 http://www.example.com/mobile-cars http://www.example.com/cars/
redirect 301 http://www.example.com/mobile-cars/for-her http://www.example.com/cars-for-her/
redirect 301 http://www.example.com/mobile-cars/for-him http://www.example.com/cars-for-him/
redirect 301 /mobile-cars/for-her/kia-moto http://www.example.com/kia-12.html
```

The first redirect is conflicting with the all others (I assume its because the first one is always part of the other domains). Even if I get rid of http://www.example.com/ and just try to redirect the queries it doesn't work.

Is there any parameter which prevents using a redirect for following redirects or something else?

Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep specific redirects before the generic catch-all ones:

```
redirect 301 /mobile-cars/for-her/kia-moto /kia-12.html
redirect 301 /mobile-cars/for-her /cars-for-her/
redirect 301 /mobile-cars/for-him /cars-for-him/
redirect 301 /mobile-cars /cars/
```

OR using `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobile-cars/for-her/kia-moto /kia-12.html
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobile-cars/(for-her|for-him) /cars-$1/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/mobile-cars /cars/
```

Comment: Would it be possible to solve the same problem with a AWS S3 301 redirect XML configuration?

Comment: This is Apache specific. I don't have working knowledge of **XML configuration** for redirects.